# Fody weaving on a referenced project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, fody

Here is my solution structure:

```
-Soln
--ProjectA
--ProjectB
```

ProjectB is referencing ProjectA. I am trying to avoid adding the Fody nuget package to ProjectA. Is there a way to perform weaving while only having to add the Fody nuget package to ProjectB without having to add Fody to ProjectA? I have looked into "in solution weaving" (https://github.com/Fody/Home/blob/master/pages/in-solution-weaving.md) but I got this error `Error Fody: No weavers found. Add the desired weavers via their nuget package` which implies that I would still need the Fody Package on ProjectA.

Comment: Hi @Amzraptor, Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, please install Add PropertyChanged.Fody nuget package rather than

Fody. When you finish it, please build the project once which will generate the

FodyWeavers.xml. Then Add-->Existing Item--> select `FodyWeavers.xml` from the project

folder.  After that, you will not face this issue  again.

Comment: I am specifically using `Virtuosity.Fody` but I think I got what you are saying. I could be wrong, but doesn't this package technically have a dependency on Fody? Can I setup a proxy-project that applies weaving on my other referenced project somehow?

Comment: Sure, `Virtuosity.Fody` nuget package is also has an dependency `Fody`. So as I know you use `Virtuosity.Fody`, you can just install it which also installs `Fody`. Then try my remaining steps. And when you finish it, you can reference this project in another project to use its body.